# GIT Bash Cloning Error - STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: git, bash, svn

Im trying to clone a project from TortiseSVN through GIT Bash.

Part way through the cloning process an exception happens and the GIT Bash console stops cloning and shows the line: 
**"0 [main] perl 10436 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to perl.exe.stackdump"**

This creates a log file with the following content:

```
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at rip=0048360C10C
rax=000000060245EBE0 rbx=000000005219E248 rcx=000000060003A900
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=0000000000011FA2 rdi=0000000000000004
r8 =0000000000000000 r9 =0000000000000000 r10=0000000100000000
r11=000000048D78607A r12=0000000000000003 r13=000006FFFFE0FD28
r14=0000000602435240 r15=000006FFFFE0FD40
rbp=000000000008FD18 rsp=00000000FFFFB900
program=C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\perl.exe, pid 7312, thread main
cs=0033 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B
```

I have been able to clone every other project stored on SVN and I have full access to all projects so privilages is not an issue.

Does anyone know a solution to fix this or even what could be causing the issue?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: instead of the git bash I would try to clone the repo from the windows command line

Comment: Great idea! and it did clone alot more of the project but eventually it ran into the same exception "STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION"